# Funcionalidad Boton

Tags: html, ajax

Me gustaria saber si es posible agregarle una acción a un boton que se esta generando por medio de Ajax. El botón se genera en el siguiente codigo:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"ajax/api.php?accion=obtener-lista-inventario-productos",
        method:"GET",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(respuesta){
            for(var i=0;i<respuesta.length;i++){
                $('#table-inventario-producto').append(
                    '<tr id="tr-'+respuesta[i].idinventario_Producto+'">'+
                    '<td class="text-center">'+respuesta[i].nombre+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="text-center">'+respuesta[i].fechaElaboracion+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="text-center">'+respuesta[i].fechaVencimiento+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="text-center">'+respuesta[i].cantidadBandejas+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="text-center"><button id="btn-eliminar-producto" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEliminarProducto" class="btn btn-link btn-sm">Eliminar Producto</button></td>'+
                    '</tr>'
                );
            }
        },
        error:function(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes añadir el `listener` al botón directamente des del HTML de JQuery, de este modo

```
// ...
$('#table-inventario-producto').append(
    '<tr id="tr-'+respuesta[i].idinventario_Producto+'">'+
    '<td class="text-center">'+respuesta[i].nombre+'</td>'+
    '<td class="text-center">'+respuesta[i].fechaElaboracion+'</td>'+
    '<td class="text-center">'+respuesta[i].fechaVencimiento+'</td>'+
    '<td class="text-center">'+respuesta[i].cantidadBandejas+'</td>'+
    `<td class="text-center">${removeButton()}</td>`+
    '</tr>'
);
```

He separado el `string` del HTML del botón a una función para que quede un poco más limpio,

```
const removeButton = _ =>
    '<button id="btn-eliminar-producto" type="button"' +
    'data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEliminarProducto" class="btn btn-link btn-sm"'+
    ' onclick="removeRow(this)">' + // Aquí se pone el listener
    'Eliminar Producto</button>'
```

Como ves, suscribo la función `removeRow` al evento `onclick` del botón.
Ahora sólo hace falta implementar la función `removeRow` que recibe por parámetro el elemento `button`.

```
const removeRow = e => {
    const tr = e.parentNode.parentNode;
    $(`#${tr.id}`).remove();
}
```

Dada la estructura por cómo creamos el botón, sabemos que está dentro de un elemento `td` que, a su vez, está dentro del elemento `tr` el cual queremos eliminar. De ese modo sacamos la `row` de la tabla y la eliminamos aprovechando su `id`.

Espero que sirva.